# How to fetch json data in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, json, angular, http, typescript

I'm trying to display a list with data fetched from a local json file. Here is how my service looks so far.

**category.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getCategories() {
    return this._http.get('api/categories.json')
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .do(data => console.log('All; ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.log(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

here is how the **Category Menu component** where I inject it looks so far

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from '../category.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-category-menu',
  templateUrl: './category-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./category-menu.component.css']
})
export class CategoryMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage: string;
  commerceName= `El baratón`;
  categoryName = `Bebidas`;
  categories: any = 'Not assigned yet';
  hasMenu?= true;

  constructor(private _categoryService: CategoryService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    return this._categoryService.getCategories()
      .subscribe(
        categories => this.categories = categories,
        error => this.errorMessage = error
      );
  }

}
```

Now, the error I am getting in the console is a 404. For this project I have used the CLI version 1.0 and the categories.json file inside of the src/api/categories.json folder.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How do you post code block with upper "Run code snippet" function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move your `api/categories.json` to assets folder, then change url to

```
return this._http.get('/assets/api/categories.json')
```

Comment: This solved it. Thanks 

Now I don't understand why the previous approach did not work. Could you provide some further explanation?

Comment: Angular CLI will serve assets folder, which have all resources, it does not serve all project content like lite-server.

Comment: Of course once the app has a live backend (testing against local .json files is a good idea) the request will be made to a server and it may not be the same server that hosts the Angular app. If you are not sure, it might be better to use a lightweight json server such as `npm:json-server` which hosts .json files from an arbitrary folder and runs in a separate process. It also permits reading and writing them.